# How can I extract multiple fields in nushell?

Tags: nushell

I have a Nushell command:

```
cat airports.yaml | from yaml | sort-by "latitude_deg" | reverse | get 'latitude_deg,name' | first 20 | to json
```

How can I output both the name and latitude_deg fields in the table? The above does not work because it seems that `get` only gets a single value. I can `get name` and then the name is output, but was hoping to output both fields.

Here is an example record in the YAML file:

```yaml
- id: '28118'
  ident: VTBS
  type: large_airport
  name: Suvarnabhumi Airport
  latitude_deg: '13.681099891662598'
  longitude_deg: '100.74700164794922'
  elevation_ft: '5'
  continent: AS
  iso_country: TH
  iso_region: TH-10
  municipality: Bangkok
  scheduled_service: 'yes'
  gps_code: VTBS
  iata_code: BKK
  local_code:
  home_link:
  wikipedia_link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suvarnabhumi_Airport
  keywords:
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but can you provide example contents of `airports.yaml`? Otherwise we cannot help you..

Comment: I've added an example record from that file, but I don't understand why it is helpful...isn't it clear from the question that the records contain 'latitude_deg' and 'name' fields? What information was missing?

Comment: yeah, it was possible to guess. but to prevent misunderstandings and let me run it myself, it's best to have everything in the question. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
open airports.yaml | sort-by --reverse latitude_deg | select latitude_deg name | first 20 | to json
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer:

As @mb21 pointed out, this is a scenario where you'll use a `select` instead of a `get`.

#### Explanation:

The difference between the two is a common source of confusion (from what I've seen on the Nushell Discord).

In your case, to demonstrate let's start with:

```bash
let demoTable = "
- id: '28118'
  name: 'Suvarnabhumi Airport'
  latitude_deg: '13.681099891662598'
  longitude_deg: '100.74700164794922'
  wikipedia_link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suvarnabhumi_Airport
- id: '2434'
  name: 'London Heathrow Airport'
  latitude_deg: '51.4706'
  longitude_deg: '-0.461941'
  wikipedia_link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heathrow_Airport
  "
  | from yaml
```

First, we can see that the resulting Nushell data structure is a table:

```bash
> $demoTable
╭───┬───────┬─────────────────────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────╮
│ # │  id   │          name           │    latitude_deg    │   longitude_deg    │            wikipedia_link             │
├───┼───────┼─────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────┤
│ 0 │ 28118 │ Suvarnabhumi Airport    │ 13.681099891662598 │ 100.74700164794922 │ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suvarnab │
│   │       │                         │                    │                    │ humi_Airport                          │
│ 1 │ 2434  │ London Heathrow Airport │ 51.4706            │ -0.461941          │ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heathro │
│   │       │                         │                    │                    │ w_Airport                             │
╰───┴───────┴─────────────────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────╯
> $demoTable | describe
table<id: string, name: string, latitude_deg: string, longitude_deg: string, wikipedia_link: string>
```

With that in place, let's look at how `get` and `select` differ with that data:

##### `get`:

`get` will *unwrap* a *value* from the record. Since a `table` is a `list` of `record` types in Nu, unwrapping a column will return a list. E.g.,

```bash
> $demoTable | get name
╭───┬─────────────────────────╮
│ 0 │ Suvarnabhumi Airport    │
│ 1 │ London Heathrow Airport │
╰───┴─────────────────────────╯
> $demoTable | get name | describe
list<string>
```

We can drill in further as well using [cell-paths](https://www.nushell.sh/book/types_of_data.html#cell-paths).  For instance, to retrieve *just* the string value of the first item (index 0):

```bash
> $demoTable | get wikipedia_link.0
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suvarnabhumi_Airport
> $demoTable | get wikipedia_link.0 | describe
string
```

##### `select`:

`select`, on the other hand, returns a subsection of the original input.  For a table, that means that `select` will return a new table with only the selected rows or columns. In your case:

```bash
> $demoTable | select name
╭───┬─────────────────────────╮
│ # │          name           │
├───┼─────────────────────────┤
│ 0 │ Suvarnabhumi Airport    │
│ 1 │ London Heathrow Airport │
╰───┴─────────────────────────╯
```

Note the column heading - That wasn't present in the `get` version. It shows that `select` is returning a new table.

Back to your original case:

```bash
> $demoTable | select name | describe
table<gps_code: string> (stream)
> $demoTable | select latitude_deg name
╭───┬────────────────────┬─────────────────────────╮
│ # │    latitude_deg    │          name           │
├───┼────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┤
│ 0 │ 13.681099891662598 │ Suvarnabhumi Airport    │
│ 1 │ 51.4706            │ London Heathrow Airport │
╰───┴────────────────────┴─────────────────────────╯
```

##### Other notes:

- You can simply:

  ```bash
  open airports.yaml | sort-by ...
  ```

  When using `open`, Nushell will use the file extension to automatically handle the `from yaml` conversion.
- `get` operations can also typically be done by using cell-paths directly.  For instance, the following will return the same results the `get` examples above:

  ```bash
  > ($demoTable).name
  ╭───┬─────────────────────────╮
  │ 0 │ Suvarnabhumi Airport    │
  │ 1 │ London Heathrow Airport │
  ╰───┴─────────────────────────╯
  > ($demoTable).name | describe
  list<string>
  > ($demoTable).wikipedia_link.0 | describe
  string
  ```

  However, `get` is, IMHO, often more readable and (especially) composable. It also comes in handy if you need to specify the key/column name dynamically using a variable.
- This is completely personal preference, but you don't have to quote single-word key/column names in most cases.  `latitude_deg` and `"latitude_deg"` are the same thing to the parser.  This goes for most strings when there's no ambiguous meaning.